# Get maximum value for the deepest level per level?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

let's say we have the following list of dictionaries, representing like a tree, where level represents the child of the previous level (level 1 it means for example A is a child of Parent (level 0), B is a child of A (level 1), C is a child of B (level 2), D is a child of A (level 1), E is a child of D (level 2), G (level 1) is a child of Parent too (level 0).

```
list_of_dicts = [{'name': 'Parent', 'number': 1299, 'level': 0}, 
{'name': 'A', 'number': 1011, 'level': 1}, 
{'name': 'B', 'number': 789, 'level': 2}, 
{'name': 'C', 'number': 430, 'level': 3},
{'name': 'D', 'number': 300, 'level': 2}, 
{'name': 'E', 'number': -100, 'level': 3},
{'name': 'F', 'number': 74, 'level': 2}, 
{'name': 'G', 'number': 300, 'level': 1}, 
{'name': 'H', 'number': 140, 'level': 2}]
```

I want a function to extract the maximum value from the deepest level. If we have multiple children of the parent (for example, A and G which are the first level), I want to extract the child name with the maximum number from the deepest value. For this specific example, the expected output should be:

```
expected = ["C", "H"]
```

(since C is the deepest level of A /but also compared to E since they are on the maximum level for level 1, is the maximum value; and H is the deepest level of G and has also that maximum value (which is also a child of Parent - level 0).

I did try this approach, but unfortunately, something is not working properly.

```
def extract_max_values(data):
    max_values = {}
    
    for item in data:
        node_name = item['name']
        node_number = item['number']
        node_level = item['level']
        
        if node_level not in max_values or node_number > max_values[node_level]['number']:
            max_values[node_level] = {'name': [node_name], 'number': node_number}
        elif node_number == max_values[node_level]['number']:
            max_values[node_level]['name'].append(node_name)
    
    deepest_level = max(max_values.keys())
    result = max_values[deepest_level]['name']

    return result
```

Comment: Can you please explain why the pandas and numpy tags are relevant?

Comment: maybe it can be found a workaround by using them. But will edit the post anyway :)

Comment: That's not a tree. For example, what is the parent of `'E'`?

Comment: parent of E is D (since the previous level is represented by D with level 2)

Comment: Can you provide a schematic of this graph for clarity? Are all level 2 nodes parents of all level 3 nodes?

Comment: It appears that the order in the list matters. Is it correct to say that if a node has a higher level then the previous entry then it is a child of that previous entry? And if the node has a smaller entry then it is a child of the whichever entry has a lower level and came before it in the list? Is that correct?

Comment: @jared that's what I was wondering, and which is currently unclear ;)

Comment: A one-dimensional list of dictionaries is almost certainly not the ideal way to [try to] represent any kind of "tree"

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, it is a little bit like python program abstract tree. "Level" being the indentation. Each line is children of the latest previous line whose indentation is smaller (so, yes, order is important).

Answer (score 0):

So, the hardest part is to turn this into a tree parsing.

This can be done that way

```py
L = [{'name': 'Parent', 'number': 1299, 'level': 0}, 
{'name': 'A', 'number': 1011, 'level': 1}, 
{'name': 'B', 'number': 789, 'level': 2}, 
{'name': 'C', 'number': 430, 'level': 3},
{'name': 'D', 'number': 300, 'level': 2}, 
{'name': 'E', 'number': -100, 'level': 3},
{'name': 'F', 'number': 74, 'level': 2}, 
{'name': 'G', 'number': 300, 'level': 1}, 
{'name': 'H', 'number': 140, 'level': 2}]


def best(a,b):
    if a is None:
        return b
    if a[1]<b[1]:
        return b
    if a[1]==b[1] and a[2]<b[2]:
        return b
    return a

def compMx(L, start=0):
    lv=L[start]['level']
    L[start]['mx'] = (L[start]['name'], lv, L[start]['number'])  
    i=start+1
    while i<len(L):
        if L[i]['level']<= lv:
            return i
        j=compMx(L, i)
        L[start]['mx'] = best(L[start]['mx'], L[i]['mx'])
        if j<0: break
        i=j
    return -1

compMx(L)
print([d['mx'][0] for d in L if d['level']==1])
```

I use a triplet (node name, level, number) to keep tracks of the answer and its scoring.

`best(t1, t2)` compare 2 triplets and return the best (the deepest, or, if they are equally deep, the highest number)

And the core part is the `compMx` function. That iterates all lines after a starting one, until it reaches a line with a smaller or equal level .
And calls recursively itself with its child (lines with with higher level).
The advancement from one child to another is done by the return value: it returns the index for the next child (next line of the same or smaller level).

So `compMx(start)`, basically (in addition to its side effect) is a function that tells you which is the next sibbling of start. And walk recursively through the tree.

It sides effect, here, is to let, before leaving, on each node Start, the "best" node of the subtree whose root is Start (it could be done by returning, in addition to next line, the said best node).

Then, once your tree is decorated, you can just, since that is apparently what you are interested in (best leaf of subtrees, not of level 0, nor level2, but level 1), filter what you want.